# Springboot BackEnd. How to receive an Object from FrontEnd(JSON type) that has an ARRAY in it

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, vue.js

I am writing a fullstack Web selling clothes and have a problem in data transferring bw FE & BE.

My Vue application send an JSON object to Backend that look like this:

```
{
"customer":{"name": "abc", "phone":"01234"},
"cart":[
         {"id":"1", "quantity":"2"},
         {"id":"2", "quantity":"3"},
       ]
}
```

as my Vue code front End send this request:

```
    let dataSend = { customer: this.customer, cart: this.cart, code: this.code };
    await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/submitOrder", dataSend)
```

this.cart is an Array that hold id and quantity of each product [{id:1, quantity:2},{...}]

at the backend I write by Java springboot I write the Controller like this

```java
@PostMapping(path="/submitOrder", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> submitNewOrder(@RequestBody Order newOrder) throws Exception {
        boolean isSuccess = orderService.checkOrderAndConductReceipt(newOrder);
        if(isSuccess)
            return new ResponseEntity("Accept", HttpStatus.OK);
        else
            return new ResponseEntity("Error, denial", HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
```

my Order model look like:

```java
@Data
public class Order {
    //Customer info
    private Customer customer;

    //his/her cart
    private Cart cart;
}
```

CART

```java
public class Cart {
    private List<ProductInCart> productList;

    public List<ProductInCart> getProductList() {
        return productList;
    }

    public void setProductList(List<ProductInCart> productList) {
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    public Cart(List<ProductInCart> productList) {
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    public Cart() {}
}
```

ProductInCart

```java
@Data
public class ProductInCart {
    private int id;
    private int quantity;
}
```

But finally, my BackEnd cannot Parse the CART from Array to a List of Product.
The error look like this:

```
.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.shopClothes.BE.HW20.demo.Model.Cart` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.shopClothes.BE.HW20.demo.Model.Cart` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 109] (through reference chain: com.shopClothes.BE.HW20.demo.Model.Order["cart"])]
```

When I try to Json.stringify the Cart array before sending like this:

```
let dataSend = { customer: this.customer, cart: JSON.stringify(this.cart), code: this.code };
```

the Error turn to:

```
.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.shopClothes.BE.HW20.demo.Model.Cart` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('[{"id":2,"quantity":3},{"id":3,"quantity":2},{"id":1,"quantity":1},{"id":5,"quantity":1}]'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.shopClothes.BE.HW20.demo.Model.Cart` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('[{"id":2,"quantity":3},{"id":3,"quantity":2},{"id":1,"quantity":1},{"id":5,"quantity":1}]')
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 109] (through reference chain: com.shopClothes.BE.HW20.demo.Model.Order["cart"])]
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: In your Order Dao take `private List<Cart> cart`  and in your Cart class have the @Data
`public class Cart {
    private int id;
    private int quantity;
}`
No need of additional class with productInCart

Comment: My order only has 1 Cart, and my Cart has multiple products. So I can do as your suggestion

Comment: Thank you, now I see it as Fabrizio point out! I see my flaw

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
@Data
public class Order {
    //Customer info
    private Customer customer;

    //his/her cart
    private List<ProductInCart> cart;
}
```

You have to change the model you are getting as request body

Comment: I think there is a misunderstood. Because, my Order only contains 1 Cart. And My Cart has multiple products inside it. So my Cart has a List of products

Comment: It's not a misunderstood, if you wan't deserialize the json you posted this is the right way. If you put a Cart instead of List<ProductInCart> the resulting json would be the following {
   "customer":{
      "name":"abc",
      "phone":"01234"
   },
   "cart": {
    "cart":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "quantity":"2"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "quantity":"3"
      }
   ] 
   }
}

Comment: Wow, fabrizio. Now I see it, the code has run. You've saved my day/ Thank you man